# Trigonometry equation. ($(\sin(x) - \sin(y))^2 + \sin^4(y) = 0)$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve a trigonometry equation, got to some point, and couldn't continue.
Here's the problem:

> $\sin^2(x) - 2\sin(x)\sin(y) - 3\cos^2(y) + \cos^4(y) + 2 = 0$

And I solved it up to here:

> $(\sin(x) - \sin(y))^2 + \sin^4(y) = 0$

I don't need a full solution, only a hint, to point me in the right direction.
Thank you :)

Comment: Hint: The square of a number is always nonnegative. How can two nonnegative numbers sum to 0?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much @eyeballfrog

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also write the equation
$$
(\sin(x)-\sin(y))^2 + (\cos^2 (x)-1)^2=0
$$
Both terms are only identically zero when $x =n\pi$ and $y=n\pi$ with $n$ an integer.